# Subtracting an exact amount of pixels from a relative value

Tags: css, html

In my CSS, I need to make the width of a div 100% - 10px.  Is this possible?  If so, how?

Pretty straight forward and simple.

Comment: hm... depends... best way I can think of is with a wrapper... can we have some sample code to better answer your question?

Comment: You can't calculate values in css. If you provide the specific problem, someone could point out a solution.

Comment: You can often use wrappers or `padding` / `margin` values as @Joseph says, but fundamentally, this is not possible.

Comment: `<div class="wrapper"><div class="content"></div></div>` <-- that's a wrapper.  You can set the width of the wrapper to 100% and give the content one a margin of 10px or whatnot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in CSS. You simply can't do any calculations in CSS. You'll have to rely on Javascript for that.

If you *absolutely* need it to work through CSS only, you should wrap it in a div with a padding.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

And here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sZvDY/

Comment: What would be the best way to do this in Javascript?  Can you perhaps provide a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Use a margin set it to 5px left and right if you want it centered or 10px either side.

Comment: the problem with that is you end up with a 100% + 10px width element

Comment: It will actually overflow if I do this because the DIV will try to keep it size.